# Duplicate release published using conventional-github-releaser

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, github-actions

I am using conventional-github-releaser and this is resulting in duplicate releases being published. One is proper and other one is dummy.

My workflow file

```
jobs:
  release:
    name: Publish New GitHub Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Extract Version
        id: extract-version
        run: |
          branch_name="${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}"
          version=${branch_name#hotfix-}
          version=${version#release/v}

          echo "release_version=$version" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Install Dependencies
        env:
          HUSKY: 0
        run: |
          npm ci

      # In order to make a commit, we need to initialize a user.
      # You may choose to write something less generic here if you want, it doesn't matter functionality wise.
      - name: Initialize Mandatory Git Config
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config --global user.email "noreply@github.com"

      - name: Tag & Create GitHub Release
        id: create_release
        env:
          HUSKY: 0
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
          CONVENTIONAL_GITHUB_RELEASER_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
        run: |
          git fetch --tags origin
          git tag -a v${{ steps.extract-version.outputs.release_version }} -m "chore: release v${{ steps.extract-version.outputs.release_version }}"
          git push origin refs/tags/v${{ steps.extract-version.outputs.release_version }}
          npm run release:github
          echo "DATE=$(date)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

[image]

```
Script
    "release:github": "DEBUG=conventional-github-releaser npx conventional-github-releaser -p angular --config github-release.config.js",
```

I tried searching online but couldn't find solution to this issue. can someone please help regarding this issue.